# Apache Sling ScheduledJobInfo

Tags: apache, osgi, scheduler, sling

I am trying to implement a Job Management module for one of the requirement and came across ScheduleJobInfo as part of the Apache Sling eventing framework. Just wondering if a Job created with a ScheduleJobBuilder can be queried through JobManager interface. If I understands jobs added through JobManager are qued up based on the topics. Would like to understand if I can check the status of Jobs through the ScheduleBuilder interface.

I am using Apache sling version 8 API

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Would like to understand if I can check the status of Jobs through the ScheduleBuilder interface.

You can't check the status of a scheduled job through the `ScheduleBuilder` API. This API only allows to schedule/suspend jobs.

In order to check the status of a scheduled job, you would need to use the regular [JobManager](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling8/index.html?org/apache/sling/commons/scheduler/Scheduler.html) API.

Indeed, regular jobs are queued when the schedule is reached. 
Quoting the [scheduled jobs](https://sling.apache.org/documentation/bundles/apache-sling-eventing-and-job-handling.html) section of the Sling documentation:

> When the scheduled time is reached, the job is automatically added as regular Sling Job through the JobManager.